# Passing Username and UserID Parameter to WebChat using WebChat Hooks API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, botframework, web-chat

I used to be able to pass the `Username` and `UserID` parameter from the URI using the below code on Webchat:

```
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var user = urlParams.get('userid')
    var usern = urlParams.get('username')
```

and I pass it on to the Webchat using the below code:

```
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: }),
        store,
        userID: user,
        username: usern,
        styleOptions
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

Now this works perfectly before when I was using the usual Webchat for the Botframework. Its no longer working when I started using ReachJS on the Webchat. How do I pass this parameter using the Webchat Hooks API? I tried specifying it using the below code but does not work.

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Composer directLine={window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: })}>
        <BasicWebChat />
        <SendMessageOnConnect />
        <user />
        <usern />
      </Composer>,
      document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in my React project. Your implementation is different, but this should put you in the right direction. You can see in the listed activity that the user `name` is updated to 'Steve'. In my case, `id` is not updated because I am generating an id with the token. When an id is generated via Direct Line with the token, it takes precedence over any id's passed via Web Chat.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class WebChatView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      usern: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var user = urlParams.get('userid');
    var usern = urlParams.get('username');
    this.setState({ user: user, usern: usern })
    this.fetchToken();
  }
  
  async fetchToken() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    this.setState(() => ({
      directLine: createDirectLine({ token: token })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.directLine ?
        <ReactWebChat
          directLine={this.state.directLine}
          userID={this.state.user}
          username={this.state.usern}
        />
        :
        <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Activity output:**

```js
{
  type: 'message',
  id: '4wpfp......-f|0000002',
  timestamp: 2020-09-02T21:39:01.197Z,
  serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: { id: 'dl_15990824712200.ruhpue7p1j', name: 'Steve', role: 'user' },
  conversation: { id: '4wpfp......-f' },
  recipient: { id: 'botberg@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Bot' },      
  textFormat: 'plain',
  locale: 'en-US',
  text: 'Hi',
  entities: [
    {
      type: 'ClientCapabilities',
      requiresBotState: true,
      supportsListening: true,
      supportsTts: true
    }
  ],
  channelData: {
    clientActivityID: '1599082740974mexnvax1jq',
    clientTimestamp: '2020-09-02T21:39:00.974Z'
  },
  rawTimestamp: '2020-09-02T21:39:01.1971653Z',
  callerId: 'urn:botframework:azure'
}
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you so much Steven! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`useParams()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook instead as:

```
let { userid, username } = useParams();
```

Or rename as the following:

```
let { userid: user, username: usern } = useParams();
```

Read further in the [documentation here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) which states:

> `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access `match.params` of the current `<Route>`.

Or you can also use [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook as:

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const { userid, username } = search;
```

Read from the documentation:

> The `useLocation` hook returns the location object that represents the current URL. You can think about it like a `useState` that returns a new location whenever the URL changes.

Comment: Thank you but I tried it but didn't work, the WebChat hooks are limited to the ones specified on the documentation which can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md